# Python string comparison, user input -> mariadb

Tags: python, string, mariadb, comparison-operators

I need help in string comparison. I know there are many questions with this topic but none of them seem to help in my problem. This program gets location coordinates according to user input and then checks if that location is already in database, if not, then location and its coordinates are updated there. 
When user_input table in the database is empty, data is inserted to database without a problem. Problem lies in string comparison where existing locations from the database are compared with user input (item == loc), even when the record is already in the database, script tries to insert it there. How to make the comparison work? All the help is appreciated.

```
    def cordinates(address):
            import requests
            url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%s" % 
            (address)
            reply = requests.get(url).json()
            loc = reply['results'][0]['address_components'][0]['long_name']
            lat = reply['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat']
        lng = reply['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng']
        return (loc,lat,lng)

    def selecting():
        import pymysql
        db = pymysql.connect('localhost','vagrant','vagrant' 
        ,database='coordinatesdb')
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute('select loc from user_input;')
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        cursor.close()
        return results

    def inserting(loc, lat, lng):
        import pymysql
        db = pymysql.connect('localhost','vagrant','vagrant', 
        database='coordinatesdb')
        cursor = db.cursor()
        new_row = "insert into user_input (loc, lat, lng) values (%s, %s, %s)"
        cursor.execute(new_row, (loc, lat, lng))
        db.commit()
        cursor.close()

    address = input('Type loc: ')
    a=cordinates(address)
    loc = a[0]
    lat = a[1]
    lng = a[2]
    select_results = selecting()

    if not select_results:
    inserting(loc, lat, lng)
    print('Inserting as table is empty')
    exit

def cordinates(address):
    import requests
    url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%s" % (address)
    reply = requests.get(url).json()
    loc = reply['results'][0]['address_components'][0]['long_name']
    lat = reply['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat']
    lng = reply['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng']
    return (loc,lat,lng)

def selecting():
    import pymysql
    db = pymysql.connect('localhost','vagrant','vagrant' ,database='coordinatesdb')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute('select loc from user_input;')
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    return results

def inserting(loc, lat, lng):
    import pymysql
    db = pymysql.connect('localhost','vagrant','vagrant', 
    database='coordinatesdb')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    new_row = "insert into user_input (loc, lat, lng) values (%s, %s, %s)"
    cursor.execute(new_row, (loc, lat, lng))
    db.commit()
    cursor.close()

    address = input('Type loc: ')
    a=cordinates(address)
    loc = a[0]
    lat = a[1]
    lng = a[2]
    select_results = selecting()

    if not select_results:
        inserting(loc, lat, lng)
        print('Inserting as table is empty')
    exit

    for item in select_results:
        if item == loc:
           print('Record is already in the database')
           quit()


    inserting(loc, lat, lng)
    print('Inserting')
```

Comment: print item and loc in your for loop, see if they are what you think they should be.  they probably aren't

Comment: Printed, they are not the same as you suspected, item is ('Helsinki',) and loc is Helsinki

Comment: How to trim parenthesis away from sql output?

Comment: if item.split("'")[1] == loc:

This should work, although it doesn't really address the root cause of the problem.

Comment: This works! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Connect only once per program, *not* once per query.